# JpGraph small demo is not working

Tags: php, jpgraph

I'm going to use [JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/download/) in my web-project. To do this, I downloaded the library into my project folder and created the following test code:

```
        <?php
        include ( "jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph.php");
        include ("jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph_gantt.php");

        // A new graph with automatic size
        $graph = new GanttGraph (0,0, "auto");

        //  A new activity on row '0'
        $activity = new GanttBar (0,"Project", "2001-12-21", "2002-02-20");
        $graph->Add( $activity);

        // Display the Gantt chart
        $graph->Stroke();
        ?>
```

The error message is:

```
The image “http://localhost:10088/test/check.php” cannot be displayed, 
because it contains errors.
```

What's wrong with my code? In fact, it was just copied from [here](http://www.aip.de/~weber/doc/jpgraph/docs/html/5gantt.html). The only thing I changed was the path to the JpGraph library. So, do I need to import this library in some special way into my project (so far, I've just copied the JpGraph's folder into the project's folder)? I'm using Zend Studio.

Comment: Take at a look at the html soucre of your graph

Comment: This code works fine for me. Mysterious. Did you double-check the paths to the files you're including?

Comment: @FrederickBehrends there is no html source. jpgraph generates an actual image file.

Comment: @octern: yes,I 100-times checked the paths...

Comment: @octern but php errors are still in the output if they are there

Comment: @FrederickBehrends When you run that script, you get a binary. There is no associated html file. Errors might show up in the system log, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by extra whitespace on the page. Make sure you don't have any spaces or line breaks before your opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: Yeaaa,that's the case. Stuuuupid mistake:)

Comment: I was also having the same problem stupid white space mistake thanks @octern for catching that silly mistake :-)